# Checking through an expression

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, expression-test

I am writing a code that manipulates expressions that contains functions with an arbitrary number of arguments.  An example expression is

```
expr = x f[a, b, c, d] - 4 f[b, a, d] + z f[] + f[a, b, d] - f[a]f[b,d]
```

What I would like to do is to make my code to be a little user-friendly by making it throw a message if the expression is invalid.  Basically, the only symbols allowed to appear in `f` are `allowedList={a,b,d}`, and so I probably need to somehow use `Scan` to check through `expr`.  (The above example should yield an 'error' since the first term has a `c` in it.)

To make answering easier, please assume that the input `expr` will be such that all arguments will have `Head = Symbol`.  But please allow for the possibility that multiple `f`s could be multiplied together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function yields `True` if the expression `expr` is valid, otherwise it yields `False`:

```
validExpressionQ[ expr_, allowedList_List] := 
  Union @ Cases[ Variables[expr], f_[x___] :> x, Infinity] == Union @ allowedList
```

now we have, e.g.

```
validExpressionQ[ x f[a, b, d] - 4 f[b, a, d] + z f[] + f[a, b, d] - f[a] f[b, d], 
                  {a, b, d}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
validExpressionQ[ x f[a, b, c, d] - 4 f[b, a, d] + z f[] + f[a, b, d] - f[a] f[b, d],
                  {a, b, d}]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Comment: I guess it should work even if `f` has DownValues

Comment: not sure, BTW :)

Comment: Very nice.  In the right hand side, would it still work if I replaced `Union @ allowedList` with just `allowedList`?

Comment: @QuantumDot No, `Union` sorts the list, it might be replaced with `Sort` but then it doesn't delete duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

A possibility is to define a support function:

**EDIT**: Thanks to Simon Woods' comment: .. instead of __

```
check[(a | b | d) ..] := 1;
check[___] = Indeterminate;
```

The substitution

```
expr /. f-> check
```

contains Indeterminate if f has arguments not allowed.

Concluding:

```
If[FreeQ[expr /. f -> check, Indeterminate], "ok", "error"]
```

returns "error" for your example and "ok" if the arguments are acceptable.

Comment: `check[a, b]` returns `Indeterminate`. Perhaps you intended to use `RepeatedNull` rather than `BlankSequence` ?

Comment: I just posted something very similar before reading this answer. +1!  Nevertheless I think my code has advantages.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems that evaluation of the expression is specifically permitted let's leverage that:

```
check[expr_, f_, pat_] := FreeQ[expr /. f[pat ...] -> 1, _f]

check[expr, f, a | b | d]
check[expr, f, a | b | c | d]
```

> ```
> False
>
> True
> ```

I used `Alternatives` instead of `List` to make this cleaner, but you can always `Apply` `Alternatives` if needed.

If for some reason you don't like the method above, here is my take on Artes's method:

```
check2[expr_, f_, args_] :=
  {} === Complement[Cases[expr, f[x___] :> x, -2], args]

check2[expr, f, {a, b, d}]
check2[expr, f, {a, b, c, d}]
```

> ```
> False
>
> True
> ```